# jQuery optimize code of multiple hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, indexing, hover

Here's my code:

```
$('.tab_map1 area').hover(function(){
    $('#nav1').find('a').stop().toggleClass('hover', 500);
        return false;
});
$('.tab_map2 area').hover(function(){
    $('#nav2').find('a').stop().toggleClass('hover', 500);
        return false;
});
$('.tab_map3 area').hover(function(){
    $('#nav3').find('a').stop().toggleClass('hover', 500);
        return false;
});
$('.tab_map4 area').hover(function(){
    $('#nav4').find('a').stop().toggleClass('hover', 500);
        return false;
});

... (there's 8 of them)
```

I'd like to not repeat the same code multiple times but optimize it somehow. Is there a chance to replace .tab_map1-8 and #nav1-8 with some index value?

I tried:

```
var n = 8;
$('li.tab_map area').eq(n).hover(function(){
    $('#nav').eq(n).find('a').stop().toggleClass('hover', 500);
        return false;
});
```

and:

```
$("#navibar ul").each(function(index) {
$('.tab_map:eq(' + index + ') area').hover(function(index){
    $('#nav:eq(' + index + ')').find('a').stop().toggleClass('hover', 500);
        return false;
});
});
```

Both doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use a `for` loop over the range 1-8.  Then build up the selector for each index.  For example

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  var helper = function (sel, id) {
    $(sel).hover(function() {
      $(id).find('a').stop().toggleClass('hover', 500);
      return false;
    });
  };

  helper('.tab_map' + i + ' area', '#nav' + i);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seems to work. I guess it's because of map/area - they are harder to handle. Here is live example how it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/LsAEu/

Comment: @Annaccond my bad. I felt right into the javascript loop capture problem.  Here is a fiddle that works.  I'll update my answer http://jsfiddle.net/LsAEu/